# How would I allow a user to visit a specific route for just one time only?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a very simple web application in Node.js, where a user is successfully redirected to a specific route (based on the current date), after they enter a token which is checked in a JSON file on the server. The user is only allowed to be redirected to the specific route once. Any subsequent GET requests to that same route should redirect to a page where the user is notified that he/she is not able to visit that specific page anymore.

I have tried to do something with `localStorage` on the frontend, but I think it is impossible to get the user to redirect on the frontend of the website. Maybe I can do something with cookies, but I have no experience working with that, and I seem to be a bit lost on how to implement such a feature on my website.

I make use of an npm package called `dayjs` to check the date on the server. LocationDate and TimeDate are variables where a date is stored.
The `req.body.token` value is fetched from a form on the home page of the website. The users are saved in a `users` variable, referring to a database.json file on the srever.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        // This checks if a token exists in the database
    const tokenValue = req.body.token
    let query = users.find(({token}) => token == tokenValue)
    name = query.name

        // This checks the date, and redirects the user to a specific route based on the date
    if (dayjs().isBefore(dayjs(LocationDate))) {
        res.redirect('/location')
        console.log(name)
    } else if (dayjs().isAfter(LocationDate) && dayjs().isBefore(TimeDate)){
        res.redirect('/date')
        console.log(name)
    } else {
        res.redirect('/time')
    }
})
```

My question would be: how would I detect if a user has visited a page after a successful redirect from the home page, and how would I disallow this user to visit this page again?

Comment: _“but I think it is impossible to get the user to redirect on the frontend of the website”_ - `location.href = …`

Comment: @misorude if you want to be sure he user only visit the page once you shouldnt do the check on client side since that can easily be manipulated and could cause a security risk (depending on the OP usecase).

Comment: @MarkBaijens sure, but then you would need an actual login to begin with. A mere session won’t do, because then I’d simply delete the session cookie and start a new one.

Comment: Removing the token from the JSON data source once it gets used, could be another option.

Comment: @misorude Your right with that, read over the token part.